# Chaining futures and options idiomatically

Tags: scala, coding-style, future, option-type

```
def foo(user, id): Future[Option[Bar]] =
  bar(user, id).map(_.map(_.address.flatMap(_.street)))
    .flatMap {
      case Some(street) =>
        baz(user, street).flatMap(_ => get(id))
      case None => successful(None)
    }
```

Function bar returns an `Option[UserInfo]`, which I then map to a `UserInfo`. `Address` is also an `Option` so I flatMap that to have access to `street`. Then simply if there exists a street I want to call `baz`, if not then `None`. Ignore the business logic, it's made up for the example.

There's a problem with the code here as it won't compile.

`Some(street)` is an `Option`, since the `flatMap` on line 3 is being called on the result of the mapping on the first `_`, instead of `_.address`.

Whilst I could get this to work with some parenthesis juggling and so on, this code is starting to get hard to read and reason about.

Are for-comprehensions the answer?

P.S: There might be some type-information missing in this example so please ask and I will elaborate.

EDIT:

`case class UserInfo(id: UserId, address: Option[Address])`

`case class Address(street: Option[List[Street]], state: Option[State])`

Comment: can you add your case classes here ? I think using `for` comprehension will help. But if you can add your case class its easier to play around in code.

Comment: Added the case classes.

Comment: As it does not compile, it is hard to play with code. For-comprehension might work but noway to test and see. It will be easier to have a code which compiles. Try giving a dummy implementations of the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood method signatures right:

```
 def bar(user, id): Option[UserInfo]
 def baz(user, List[Street]): Future[BarId]
 def get(id): Option[Bar]
```

You can implement your method something like this:

```
val streetsOpt: Option[List[Street]] = bar(user, id).flatMap(_.flatMap(_.address.flatMap(_.street)))

streetsOpt.flatMap(streets => {
    baz(user, streets).map(_ => get(id))
}).getOrElse(successful(None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly looking at this, within this line:

```
baz(user, street).flatMap(_ => get(id))
```

I don't think that the last flatMap won't work properly because you seem to be passing in a function  which is of a type something like:

```
f: => A
```

i.e. extracting the underlying value from some context, whereas flatMap expects you to unpack this value and then wrap in a new context, and so has type:

```
f: A => M[B]
```

When you are making the call to

```
get(id)
```

Shouldn't this be being applied to a map method instead, which expects a function of type:

```
f: A => B
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of dealing with nested contexts like this. [I gave a talk](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5520-stacking-monads-high) about three that I know: monad transformers (explicit, more "standard", but a bit more verbose), Kleisli (very elegant, if you're willing to write in pointfree style), or my [scalaz-transfigure](https://github.com/m50d/scalaz-transfigure) library (a bit immature, a bit less explicit, but very concise).